# Git automatic merge commit message

Tags: git

I have split one giant repo into several small ones.  The old repo is still being comited to so I have to keep updating my new smaller ones.

I did this by doing this:

```
git subtree split -P some-sub-directory-in-my-large-repo/ -b branch-name-I-split
```

Obviously,  I am trying to script this out, but I can't get past this:

```
cd my-smaller-repo
git pull /path-to-large-repo/ branch-name-I-split
```

And that of course brings me to the editor.

I need to just accept the default message and move on...

Any ideas?

Comment: How is it smaller?

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 6):

You can use the --no-edit flag to accomplish this.

From the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-options#Documentation/merge-options.txt---edit)

```
--edit
-e
--no-edit
Invoke an editor before committing successful mechanical merge to further 
edit the auto-generated merge message, so that the user can explain and 
justify the merge. The --no-edit option can be used to accept the auto- 
generated message (this is generally discouraged). The --edit (or -e) 
option is still useful if you are giving a draft message with the -m 
option from the command line and want to edit it in the editor.

Older scripts may depend on the historical behaviour of not allowing the 
user to edit the merge log message. They will see an editor opened when 
they run git merge. To make it easier to adjust such scripts to the 
updated behaviour, the environment variable GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT can be set 
to no at the beginning of them.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your smaller repo probably has a different log of commits than the large one. So when you try to pull, it will merge the large one in the small one. Because it makes a merge, your editor is open. To quit it, it depends on the editor:

- if it is nano, you can quit it with `ctrl-x`
- if it is vim, you can quit it with `:q`
- if it is emacs, you can quit it with `ctrl-x ctrl-c`
- otherwise, it'll depend on the editor, a screenshot would help us knowing which one it is.

If you don't want the editor to be spawned, you can use `git merge` instead of `git pull`:

```
git fetch remote-name
git merge remote-name/branch-name -m "Merge message"
```

Comment: Right,  but how do I do it from the command line?  Like with a commit -m  But that does not work with a pull

Comment: I updated to be able to merge and setting the message without having the editor being spawned.

Comment: So what exactly, is "remote-name"  -- does this mean that my smaller branches need to be committed to the remote repository?  (right now it's only local)

Comment: `remote-name` is your `/path-to-large-repo/`. I just read the doc and saw that `git pull` accepts paths and urls as first argument

Comment: So the git fetch is working,  but the merge is not.  I am getting  "merge: /path-to-large-repo/branch-name - not something we can merge

Comment: Apologies, for the merge you will then need to have the large repo set as a a remote, with: `git remote add large-repo /path-to-large-repo/`, then you can do `git fetch` and `git merge large-repo/branch-name -m "Merge message"